# Сбор данных из нескольких файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Как собрать и сохранить данные с множества однородных таблиц в формате `.dat`, так, чтобы программа брала только одну ячейку - `data.RadVel[0]`, и сохраняла всё в ОДИН файл в таком виде `<имя файла>_<величина из ячейки>`:

```
file1.dat 36.8
file2.dat 36.2
```

*Мой код:*

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = 'D:/Python/Sp'
os.chdir('D:/Python/Sp')
for file in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    data = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\s+', engine='python')
    print(file, data.RadVel[0])
```

Comment: В чём именно у вас сложность?

Answer (score 2):

Код по описанию из вопроса:

```
data = []

for file in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', engine='python', usecols=['RadVel'], nrows=2)
    data.append([file, df.loc[0, 'RadVel']])

res = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['file', 'val'])
res.to_csv('result.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

**NOTE:** данный код не тестировался по причине отсутствия в вопросе [воспроизводимого примера данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за внимание, решил сам проблему!

```
d=str(data.RadVel[0])
dat=open('data.txt','a')
dat.write(d+'\n')
dat.close()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Очень неэффективно каждый раз открывать и закрывать файл в цикле. Кроме того - в вопросе вы указали на необходимость сохранения имени файла в результирующем файле - не вижу где это реализовано в данном ответе